# Curious about the way to calculate area of histogram rectangle

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have self-studied the book “Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences 9th Edition”. From the following paragraph (about histogram construction) on the page 17

> This construction ensures that the area of each rectangle is proportional to the relative frequency of the value. Thus if the relative frequencies of x=1 and x=5 are 0.35 and 0.07, respectively, then the area of the rectangle above 1 is five times the area of the rectangle above 5.

I am curious, why does the area of the rectangle above 1 deals with the five and the area of the rectangle above 5? why is it not width of the rectangle times 0.35 (which is hight)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47HrL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the interval's lenth is $1$, so your area is width$\times$height $=$ height

Answer (score 0):

There should be a picture in the book to accompany this paragraph. In that picture the rectangle above $x=1$ has base $1$ and height $0.35$, so area $0.35$. The rectangle above $5$ has height (and area) $0.07$. The first rectangle is five times as high (and has five times the area) of the second, because $0.35/0.07 = 5$.

It is just a *coincidence* that the second rectangle corresponds to the value of $5$ and is one fifth the size. In general, the value on the $x$ axis and the height are not related numerically. I think the author of the book chose a confusing example to make this point.